# Can't find exact text in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a problem here where I need to search for an exact text using selenium. I would like to search for exact text with value "SER20170905111755" but in actual fact, there is another similar text with value "SER20170905111755 - AF-CR-613" on the page also.

I have tried using this

```
String text = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(., 'SER20170905104010')]"))).getText();
```

it returns "SER20170905111755 - AF-CR-613" to me. Then i tried with

```
String text = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[text()='SER20170905104010']"))).getText();
```

it throws TimeOut exception. Seems it can't locate the text. But, if I replace it with this

```
String text = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text()='SER20170905104010']"))).getText();
```

it returns the expected value I need, which is "SER20170905111755". Below is the HTML code of the page for both texts

1. SER20170905111755 - AF-CR-613
   [image]
2. SER20170905111755
   [image]

Can you please help how can I perform exact text search by using //* instead of //div?

Comment: use class name in xpath

Comment: Why you want to `//*` instead of `//div`

Comment: Hi Tarun, for this page, it appears in a div, but it could be at other place not in div too in other pages.

Comment: Is u find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xapths

```
//div[@class='tabHeader']
```

or

```
//div[@class='tabHeader'][contains(text(),'SER20170905111755')]
```

Comment: Hi, just one question. Why is //div working as expected but not //*?

Comment: I don't know but * find element in complete page, while //tagname search in that same type tag. I hope it helps you. also we can search with * too, why it is not working for you strange for me also

Comment: I have tried //* in firebug and it locates the text. I run the test on IE due to the requirement.

Comment: With //*, it's not working on IE. I have just tried with FireBug with //* and it matches the text I want.

Comment: Please tell me the version of IE I will try

Comment: version 11.0.9600

Comment: I don't have this version but pretty sure My xpaths are working in IE , FF and Chrome , I will try to found * issue dear. If my xpaths help me please upvote for me

Comment: Chris u will try my xpaths we will try to found why * is not work in IE

Comment: Hi, definitely your xpath is working for me. But I need to perform the search in whole page, which means it could be not under div tag too. Currently the workaround is, using a loop with both //* and //div. If the first one fails, then proceed with //div.

Comment: As I know you have to find with //div , it give you efficient result and less processing time,

Answer (score 0):

You can try using not  predicate with your xpath as below

```
By.xpath("//*[contains(., 'SER20170905104010') and not(contains(.,'SER20170905111755 - AF-CR-613'))]")
```

I am also not sure about this but just have a try and let me know.

Comment: Hi, what if I gonna replace SER20170905104010 with variable? Is there some sort like "and not *SER20170905104010*"?